# Architecting BlackBerry CRM / SFA applications

Tags: architecture, blackberry, persistence, rms

I am in process to start developing a Blackberry application (Proof Of Concept) on the lines of SalesForce and SalesNow CRM. I am a web developer with skills on LAMP technologies with a limited knowledge in JAVA /J2ME / BB Native libraries. Have gone through all the examples / samples on RIM / STACKOVERFLOW websites.

Expert advice needed on how to start developing the same with information pertaining to the following points.

1. how to implement the storage of data (Records) on device for offline browsing. (e.g. Persistent Store / RMS etc)
2. what data format to follow to download from server. (shud it be xml, string based etc)
3. sample Class design for entities like (Account, Contacts, Leads etc)
4. Sample Tabbed like interface similiar to Salesforce and SalesNow BB apps.

any pointers / suggestions / help is appreciated.

Tx in advance.

SN

Answer (score 0):

1. It'l use Persistent Storage
2. Data Format will be WSDL an XML format for describing network services as a set of endpoints operating on messages containing either document-oriented or procedure-oriented information

3.Example: 
accounts:-
Accountid
City
Country
Name
Postalcode
Region
Street
Telephone

4.Sorry haven't checked out their ui's 
U can create a grid/list kinda layout for the menu
Chk out this 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/How-to-use-Table-View-layout/ba-p/356886

Answer (score 0):

1. [Blackberry - application settings save/load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476994/blackberry-application-settings-save-load)
2. [Blackberry - send/receive XML data with webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720253/blackberry-send-receive-xml-data-with-webservice/1720720#1720720)
3. Entities should be simple (int, long, string), have int Id and implement [Persistable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Persistable.html)
4. [How To - Create a rich UI layout with TableLayoutManager](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_rich_UI_layout_with_TableLayoutManager.html?nodeid=1906675&vernum=0) (actually mentioned by Rohit Roy)