# Database Options for Blackberry

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, blackberry

Okay, I'm new to blackberry development and I was wondering if anyone could give me a list of database options available for blackberry applications? What do developer's "normally" do when faced with the requirement of utilizing a server for their blackberry applications? Is there any one specific database that is used for a majority of the applications (like Oracle?) out there now for blackberry? I did a Google search, but all I got back was old stuff that I'm sure has improved by now. I'm looking for some tutorial or explanation on how to remote connect to a database. Thanks for any help and advice you can give to a new blackberry developer!

Comment: Since you mention 'Oracle' are you talking about connecting over a network to a remote database?    Or do you want a database for data that lives on the device?

Comment: Well, I'm developing an application with another friend for a software engineering class. I have the Bold 9700 which is nice and I could possibly use SQLite but my friend has a Pearl 8120. I've search and apparently the latest OS for his phone is v4.5. Since we're doing it together as a team, we want to develop something so both of us can run tests on our phones, so we pretty much have to develop for the v4.5 platform unless there is some way around this that I don't know about (which could be very likely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blackberry OS versions 5 and up include SQLite on the device.  All devices have a proprietary storage mechanism called the Persistent Store.  (You may have to use it if you need broad device support).  There also the old cruddy J2ME 'record store' mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

I'd direct you to this page. It lists the current storage solutions for the Blackberry, and allows you to choose the best one for you.

[Data Storage Overview - BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Data_storage_overview_1219751_11.jsp)

As one previous poster suggested, SQLite is certainly a good option. It will allow you to have the flexability to use the same Database framework for other mobile apps - Android, iOS and Symbian all have the ability to use SQLite.

However, SQLite does come with some drawbacks. Query size, and pre-loading the database into RAM are probably the biggest two (so big queries and databases can be tricky) as well as the fact that your app will not be available to any pre-OS5 phones.

You should refer to this page for more information on that.

[SQLite Overview - BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/SQLite_database_performance_1228636_11.jsp)

Hope this helps,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175766/blackberry-data-persistence-o-s-4-5/2177849#2177849) for more database options for devices running an OS version less than 5 (i.e. your friend's 8120).